# Software creating user interface prototypes on Linux

Tags: prototype

I'm looking for user interface prototyping software. I like [Axure](http://www.axure.com/), but it is not available on Linux, so I'm looking something similar with it. What open source project do you use for basic UI prototyping? What are pros and cons?

P.S. Software must work on Linux.

Comment: You can use a LAMP stack for Mockuptiger (http://www.mockuptiger.com) and use it as a local desktop web based app

Answer (score 6):

We use the [Pencil project](http://pencil.evolus.vn), it uses XUL so it's multiplatform.. It's available as a Firefox addon or standalone application.

Comment: Pencil really looks nice

Answer (score 3):

[Balsamiq Mockups For Desktop](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups/desktop) is AIR-based and therefore cross-platform. Balsamiq is great because it's very straightforward as opposed to a more "enterprisey" app like Axure. It's not open-source.

Answer (score 2):

Also, http://gomockingbird.com is an online alternative to Pencil, and http://connectasketch.com is a nice way to link sketches into a navigable prototype.